# VBA duplicate string boolean function #NAME Error

Tags: excel, vba, boolean

This is probably very basic for most here, I have no background and just need some help. I have to write an isDup function in VBA to compare two tweets based on their similar word counts to determine if the tweets are duplicate or not, based on a decimal threshold chosen (0-1). If they are duplicates, the function will return true. Every time i call the function it returns a #NAME in the cell instead of a true/false, and was wondering if anyone can give me some tips or let me know what i am doing wrong. Thank you!

```
Option Explicit
Function isDup(tweet1 As String, tweet2 As String, threshold As Double) As Boolean

Set threshold = 0 - 1
Dim tweet1Split() As String
    tweet1Split = Split(tweet1, " ")

Dim tweet2Split() As String
    tweet2Split = Split(tweet2, " ")

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Dim sameCount As Integer

For i = LBound(tweet1Split) To UBound(tweet1Split) Step 1
    For j = LBound(tweet2Split) To UBound(tweet2Split) Step 1
        If StrComp(tweet1Split(i), tweet2Split(j), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            sameCount = sameCount + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i

Dim score As Double
Dim arraySize As Double
arraySize = UBound(tweet1Split) - LBound(tweet1Split) + 1
score = sameCount / arraySize

If score > threshold Then
    isDup = True
Else
    isDup = False
End If

End Function
```

Comment: `Set threshold = 0 - 1` doesn't make sense. `Set` is for object variables.

Comment: okay thank you, any suggestions on how i would make the threshold 0-1?

Comment: `threshold = 1` if I understand what you're trying to do. But I don't understand why you're trying to do this... `threshold` is a parameter already, I don't know why you'd modify it.

Comment: other than that do you see any errors with it?

Comment: Verbose code drives me nuts. At the end, you can replace five lines of code with this: `isDup = score > threshold`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Place the following in a standard code module...

```
Public Function isDup(tweet1$, tweet2$, threshold#) As Boolean

    Dim c&, i&, j&, t1, t2

    t1 = Split(tweet1, " ")
    t2 = Split(tweet1, " ")

    For i = 0 To UBound(t1)
        For j = 0 To UBound(t2)
            If Not StrComp(t1(i), t2(j), vbTextCompare) Then c = c + 1
        Next
    Next

    isDup = (c / (UBound(t2) + 1)) > threshold

End Function
```

And then use it from a worksheet:

```
=isDup(A1,A2,0.5)
```

...assuming the text of two tweets to compare is in `A1` and `A2`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting the #NAME error when trying to use a User-Defined Function in a spreadsheet, it's because Excel doesn't recognise the function. Make sure the code for the function is going in a Module in the workbook where you are trying to use the function, as per the image below.

The only change you *need* to make to the code for the function to run is to delete the line:

```
Set threshold = 0 - 1
```

You can then test to ensure it's giving the desired result.

The function isn't available if you just place it in a Sheet or ThisWorkbook object. You need to insert a Module and place the code there.

It also isn't available to other workbooks, unless you add references in those workbooks or save it to an add-in which is then correctly installed. You can look or ask for help on those processes separately if needed.

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the answer as correct to close the question. You can ask another question if you need more help.